# JasperServer MalformedURLException

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jasperserver, jaspersoft-studio, malformedurlexception

I'm using **JasperServer 4.5.0 and Jaspersoft Studio 1.1.2**.

I made ​​a report and uploaded it to the server host without problems.

But when I view it, it throws this exception message:

> com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.JSExceptionWrapper: java.net.MalformedURLException

**Trace:**

> com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.JSExceptionWrapper:
> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException:
> java.net.MalformedURLException at
> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:251)
> at
> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:230)
> at
> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:218)
> at
> com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.compileReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:905)
> at
> com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.compileReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:1362)

Do you know why I get this exception?

Comment: Can you provide full stack trace?

Comment: Some `RuntimeException` with empty message occurred in constructor `URL(URL context, String spec, URLStreamHandler handler)`, difficult to investigate.

Comment: URL path to your XML file must be wrong. Check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not what the problem was but change to iReport and I did upload the report directly to me and JasperServer and works. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you have to do that,

- Copy your Project Packages to another New Project.
- Add All Libraries
- Make The **.jrxml** File again.

**It will work.....**